# How to deserialise Json into Immutable Object - Spring, RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, linkedhashmap

I have a model that looks like this:

```
@Data
public class RegistrationRequestDto {

    public final String email;
    public final String username;
    public final String password;
    public final String confirmPassword;
    public final String firstName;
    public final String lastName;
    public final String keycloakId;

    public RegistrationRequestDto(
            String email,
            String username,
            String password,
            String confirmPassword,
            String firstName,
            String lastName,
            String keycloakId) {
        notNull(email, "email must be set");
        notNull(username, "username must be set");
        notNull(password, "password must be set");
        notNull(firstName, "firstName must be set");
        notNull(lastName, "lastName must be set");
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.keycloakId = keycloakId;
    }
}
```

Next, I have a method that is calling another service with `restTempate`.

The result of that call I should save in the model shown above.

I have this piece of code that should call and return result from external service:

```
RegistrationRequestDto userProfile = new RegistrationRequestDto();
        try {
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
            // httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + responseToken.getAccess_token());
            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(httpHeaders);

            ResponseEntity<Object> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, Object.class);
            log.info("{}", result);
            log.info("{}", result.getBody());

            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) result.getBody();

            if (map != null) {
                userProfile.setUserId(map.get("sub").toString());
                userProfile.setGiven_name(map.get("given_name").toString());
                userProfile.setFamily_name(map.get("family_name").toString());
                userProfile.setEmail(map.get("email").toString());
                userProfile.setEmail_verified(map.get("email_verified").toString());
                //userProfile.setPhoto(Optional.ofNullable(map.get("photo").toString()));
            }
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userProfile;
```

So, in this code I am using

```
if (map != null) {
   userProfile.setUserId(map.get("sub").toString());
   userProfile.setGiven_name(map.get("given_name").toString());
   userProfile.setFamily_name(map.get("family_name").toString());
   userProfile.setEmail(map.get("email").toString());
   userProfile.setEmail_verified(map.get("email_verified").toString());
}
```

Which I was able to use when variables in `RegistrationRequestDto` model were just `private`.

But now as variables are `public final` I am not sure how to store result in map?

Comment: What is that `@Data` annotation on your DTO? Is it Lombok?

Comment: Yes it is a Lombok

Comment: Why not create the contract class and pass that class type in the exchange method. It will give you parsed object instead of map.

Comment: @Pirate How would I do that? Do you maybe have example code that I can take a look into?

Comment: Final variables can only be initialized once. In the calling code you create a new DTO but with no arguments, which is valid (although I don't know why the notNull calls are not preventing this.) You then attempt to run individual setters against variables - that have already been initialized.

Comment: @RBH Yes, you are right I can't initialize, no args constructor I just left there an example code of how I did it with private variables, but now I would like to know how to do it with public ones.

Comment: If you are using java 14 or above you can use record instead of class. Record's properties are final and spring can do deserialization of record for you

Comment: I am using Java 11

Comment: You initialized your final variables (to null values) when you did this:     RegistrationRequestDto userProfile = new RegistrationRequestDto(); You can't do it again with e.g. userProfile.setUserId(map.get("sub").toString());

Comment: @user9347049 Something like "Spring RestTemplate deserialize json into Immutable Object" is a better title for your question

Comment: @MohammadYasin yes you are right, maybe something like that

Comment: @user9347049 My answer was not ok?(below answer). If you have problem with it ask freely

Comment: @user9347049 So change the title please

Comment: How would full code for restTemplate look? `User user = restTemplate.exchange..?`

Comment: var response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, User.class);

or
        ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, User.class);

Comment: and then         User user = response.getBody();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dto class must have a fasterxml @JsonCreator on its constructor.
something like below dto:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class User {
    public final int id;
    public final String name;

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public User(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And in the rest call pass `User.class` instead of `Object.class`. Something like below:

```
ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, User.class);

User user = response.getBody();
```

**Note:** `@JsonProperty("...")` is necessary here. Also `@Value` is better for your use case than `@Data`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the Pojo as per the response returned from the api.

i.e If you have some api **https://www.mockapis.not/users/user/123** and it return the response something like this,

```
{
   "name":"stack",
   "age":21,
   "phone":123456789,
   "dob":"01-06-2011"
}
```

Then you can create a java class with the given properties.

```
class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private long phone;
    private Date dob;

    //getter setter or lombok @Data or @Getter @Setter
}
```

Then you can call your api as below and you can get User object from the response entity.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.exchange(apiUrl, HttpMethod.GET, User.class);
User user = response.getBody();
```

Now you don't need to parse the object. It will be parsed by automatically.

For more details you can visit [Resttemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like to use public final variables. I know how to do it with this private ones but not with final variables and that was my question

Comment: This will not work for immutable objects

Comment: @MohammadYasin Yes this does not work for final variables, with my question I am trying to find out what works :)